# Powershell elegantly enumerate several variables

Tags: powershell

I have a text output which shows the runtimes of each selection I make in a script.

> Check Level: 0, 38.99607466333333
>
> Check Level: 1, 60.93540646055553
>
> etc.

What I'd like to do is have some read-host lines, showing a choice of what level I'd like to go to, and next to that the variable showing how long on average it takes, i.e. 'Checklevel 1 takes 60 minutes'.

The following script works, but I can't help thinking there's a better alternative:

```
$CheckLevel0 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 0,*"}
$CheckLevel1 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 1,*"}
$CheckLevel2 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 2,*"}
$CheckLevel3 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 3,*"}
$CheckLevel4 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 4,*"}
$CheckLevel5 = Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: 5,*"}
```

Ideally, I'd expect to have all the $CheckLevelx variables populated with one or two lines... I've tried all sorts.

Comment: Will there be duplicate Check Level _n_ entries?

Comment: `$n = Read-Host -Prompt "N"; Get-Content $RuntimeFile | Where {$_ -like "Check Level: $n,*"};`

Answer (score 1):

Whlist *gvee*'s solution is simple and elegant, it doesn't work if you'd like to show a menu that shows execution times too.

That being said, you are right on the track about simpler a solution. Whenever one has more than, say, three variables named *value0, value1, ... valuen*, it's usually time to use a data structure. An array would be an obvious choice, quite often a hashtable would do too. Via .Net, there are [many types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections) for more special needs.

If you need to do more complex processing with the data file, consider preprocessing it. Let's use a regex and hashtable like so,

```
# Some dummy data. Note the duplicate entry for level 1
$d = ('Check Level: 0, 38.99607466333333',` 
'Check Level: 1, 60.93540646055553',`
'Check Level: 2, 34.43543543967473',`
'Check Level: 1, 99.99990646055553')

# A regular expression to match strings
$rex = [regex]::new('Check Level: (\d+),.*')

# Populate a hashtable with contents
$ht = @{}
$d | % {
    $level = $rex.Match($_).groups[1].value
    $line = $rex.Match($_).groups[0].value
    if( $ht.ContainsKey($level)) {
        # Handle duplicates here.
        $ht[$level] = $line
    }
    else {
        $ht.Add($level, $line)
    }
}
# Print the hashtable in key order.
$ht.GetEnumerator() | sort

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              Check Level: 0, 38.99607466333333
1                              Check Level: 1, 99.99990646055553
2                              Check Level: 2, 34.43543543967473
```